# Outer Measure is not Finite Additive

Tags: measure-theory

A cube $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a subset $[a_1,b_1]\times \cdots \times [a_d,b_d]$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b_i-a_i=b_j-a_j$ for all $i,j$. By volume of cube $Q$, denoted $|Q|$, we mean $\prod_{i=1}^d(b_i-a_i)$.  The **outer measure** of a set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, denoted $m_*(E)$, is defined as infimum of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|Q_i|$ where $Q_i$'s are cubes in $\mathbb{R}^d$ which cover $E$, and infimum is taken over all such countable covers of $E$.

It is well known (Stein-Shakarchi: Real Analysis, p.14) that if distance between two subsets $E_1$ and $E_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is positive, then $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$. But why can't we allow $E_1$ and $E_2$ to be only disjoint (instead of saying distance between them is positive)?

The book mentioned above remarks this fact, and I couldn't find an example.

Comment: You may find this interesting. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878962/finite-additivity-in-outer-measure/878975#878975

Comment: @Romeo: I saw this, but I dont find an example.

Comment: @Groups Nate Eldredge gave the same answer in that thread that I did in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Write $x\sim y$ if $x-y$ is rational.  This is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$; let $E$ be a set of representatives, and define $E_r = (r+E)\cap [0,1]$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Then any cover of some $E_r$ by intervals must cover all of $[0,1]$, so $m_* (E_r)=1$ for all $r$.  But we also have $m_*(E_r\cup E_s)=1$, in fact $m_* (\bigcup_r E_r)=m_* ([0,1]) = 1$.

Comment: Why any cover of $E_i$ by intervals should cover $[0,1]$? Does this happens for set of irrationals in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Groups Because any real number may be approximated by rationals, so there is a representative of each equivalence class arbitrarily close to any point.  This does happen for the set of irrationals in $[0,1]$ (after all, they're just the union of all but one of the $E_i$), but the irrationals are measurable, so we can't use them for your original question.

Comment: Sorry! I am confused! We denote by $\{E_i\}$ the set of equivalence classes; isn't it the set of cosets of rationals in $\mathbb{Q}$? i.e. each $E_i$ is a coset of set of rationls in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Groups Correct.

Comment: Then, how $m_*(E_i)=1$? It should be zero, isn't it? Since, $E_i$ is countable, for every $\epsilon>0$, we can find a cover of $E_i$ by countable number of open intervals, the sum of whose lengths add up to $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Groups Sorry, I wrote something very different from what I intended.  I think it's fixed now.

Comment: @Every real number can be written as $n/2+l$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $0\leq l<1/2$. Then, we can choose the representatives $l$'s such that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are equivalent if and only if $l_1-l_2$ is rational. Then, the set of equivalence classes, call it $F$, is a subset of $[0,1/2)$, and it is a non-measurable set. Buy, any open cover of $F$ may not cover $[0,1]$. Thus, with the sets $E_i$'s, I couldn't understand the failure of finite additivity of outer measure.

Comment: @Groups You are right, this approach still has problems.  I'll update it if I think of a fix.  Sorry about that.