# If $\mu ^*$ is a Lebesgue exterior mesure and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $\mu ^* (A \cup B) \not = \mu ^* (A) + \mu ^* (B)$.

Tags: measure-theory

I have still have a hard time to comprehend intuitively what the Lebesgue exterior measure is really about.

Yet from such example as when the exterior measure of rectangles is equal to $(b_1 - a_1)(b_2 - a_2) ... (b_d - a_d)$ when the rectangle is in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I somehow made a conjecture that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $\mu ^* (A \cup B)  = \mu ^* (A) + \mu ^* (B)$.

Yet my teacher told me that is totally false. Can someone explain me why? And could someone give me a counter-example?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878962/finite-additivity-in-outer-measure

Comment: Your title incorrectly negates the implication $p\implies q$ with $p\implies \text{not } q$.  Negating the implication means it is *possible* to have disjoint $A$ and $B$ such that the inequality doesn't hold, not that the inequality never holds.